# How to comment a line of a XML file in C# with System.XML

Tags: c#, xml

I need to comment and uncomment the 4th line of this XML file using System.XML properties:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>    
        <system.web>
            <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="som_url_here" />
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Desired output:

```
<!-- <customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="som_url_here" /> -->
```

It's possible to achieve this without using a file reader?

The node:

```
XmlNode xmlNodoCE = docWebConfig.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("system.web/customErrors");
```

Comment: How would you expect to do this without reading the file?

Comment: With System.XML if its possible.

Comment: System.XML doesn't let you magically transform the file without reading it.

Comment: Why not use a different web.config?

Comment: Would you not be better of using config transformation files?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326.aspx

Comment: Maybe with this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmltextwriter(v=VS.90).aspx?

Comment: how about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.createcomment(v=VS.100).aspx for commenting. And here is question about uncommenting http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3677016/to-uncomment-a-commented-node-in-a-xml-file-using-c

Comment: In your comment below *"i need to conserve the value of defaultRedirect="" when i want to set it to false again"*, you do realise that if you're doing this within the application and you modify the `web.config` file your app will restart?

Comment: @Kev The IT guys told me that I should avoid that issue bacause they manage it with IIS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to

- load the file into an XmlDocument,
- retrieve the node you want to comment,
- create a comment node containing the XML content of your original node,
- add this comment to the original's parent node just before the original node
- remove it from its parent,
- write the XmlDocument to a file (the same one).

  ```
  String xmlFileName = "Sample.xml";

  // Find the proper path to the XML file
  String xmlFilePath = this.Server.MapPath(xmlFileName);

  // Create an XmlDocument
  System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDocument = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();

  // Load the XML file in to the document
  xmlDocument.Load(xmlFilePath);

  // Get the target node using XPath
  System.Xml.XmlNode elementToComment = xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("/configuration/system.web/customErrors");

  // Get the XML content of the target node
  String commentContents = elementToComment.OuterXml;

  // Create a new comment node
  // Its contents are the XML content of target node
  System.Xml.XmlComment commentNode = xmlDocument.CreateComment(commentContents);

  // Get a reference to the parent of the target node
  System.Xml.XmlNode parentNode = elementToComment.ParentNode;

  // Replace the target node with the comment
  parentNode.ReplaceChild(commentNode, elementToComment);

  xmlDocument.Save(xmlFilePath);
  ```

Comment: This is a bit specific to your xml file. In general you'd need to keep track of the position of the original target node and insert the new comment node in the same position. Let me know if you need that as well.

Comment: @langsamu But it appends to the end, is there any way to put it where it should be? I mean, put the commented line under his own comment of the XML file.   <!--  CUSTOM ERROR MESSAGES
          Set customError mode values to ... -->
    <put it here>

Comment: I don't quite understand.
Can you post original and desired XML.

Comment: @langsamu I have more nodes under <system.web> and i want to comment the line and have it where it was in the same node tree, not to append it to the end of the tree

Comment: OK. You need to use InsertBefore instead of AppendChild.
First create the comment node, then insert the comment node to the parent node before the original node, and finally remove the original node.
I'll edit the answer in a sec.

Comment: @langsamu Actually im using prepend instead of append

Comment: That would make it always the first instead of always the last. The proper solution is as per my previous comment and the edited answer.

Answer (score 4):

This should do the trick. It is a console app, but the principle is exactly the same. It does assume a file called "web.config" will be in the same folder as the exe:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load("web.config");

            var element = document.SelectSingleNode("//compilation[@defaultLanguage = 'c#' and @debug = 'true']");

            var comment = document.CreateComment(element.OuterXml);

            element.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(comment, element);

            document.Save("web.config2");

            var document2 = new XmlDocument();
            document2.Load("web.config2");

            var comment2 = document2.SelectSingleNode("//system.web/comment()");
            var newNode = document2.CreateDocumentFragment();
            newNode.InnerXml = comment2.InnerText;
            comment2.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, comment2);
            document2.Save("web.config3");

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

It's saving to different files to show the progression of the xml, obviously, you'd just want to save back to the original file.

edit: You changed the xml since I wrote the answer, but if you change the xpath then it should work exactly the same.

Answer (score -2):

the problem here is that an `XmlDocument` is a data structure for a load of XML, it will not read in the comments when it parses the file. you are trying to edit the file itself.

Comment: So if I comment the line, I can't uncomment it again?

Comment: why don't you just set it as `debug="false"`

Comment: Because i need to conserve the value of defaultRedirect="" when i want to set it to false again. @harryovers I made a mistake, OP edited.

Comment: why don't you have a `const string` for the value you need to save

Comment: Actually @harryovers `XmlDocument` will read the comments in the file. See my answer.